# how to stream a camera to users with permission

Tags: apache, streaming, video-streaming, webcam, vlc

I have a LAN at home.  One machine runs a webserver.  Another machine has a webcam.  I would like to make a webpage on the hosting machine that provides a stream from the webcam on the other computer.  The serving machine has it's own domain name/ip, but the computer with the webcam sits behind the router, using NAT.  I am no networking guru, but I am a programmer with enough knowledge of the stuff.
Basically I want the page offering the video stream to only be visible to registered users.

Is this even possible?  Currently I am using VLC to stream on the LAN.  The only way I can think to do this is to forward the port to my webcam machine, and let the webserver serve a page containing a  tag with the src being a direct url to my router and the forwarded port.

Is there an alternative where port forwarding to the webcam machine would not be necessary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a [reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) on the web server to access the webcam server. It might be sufficient to only enable `mod_proxy` and add this to your configuration:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /webcam http://webcam-server/stream-url
```

When a client connects to the web server requesting `/webcam`, the web server will in turn connect to the internal webcam server and pass the contents back to the browser.